# Pixel shader always returning white

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I have a pixel shader that tries to return a static colour

```
float4 PPBright(PS_POSTPROCESS_INPUT ppIn) : SV_Target
{
    return (1.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.0f);
}
```

no matter the colour values it returns white, I can change the alpha values and it affects the colour (white, grey, black).

here's my cpp code:

```
g_pd3dDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &BackBufferRenderTarget, DepthStencilView);
BloomTextureVar->SetResource(SceneShaderResource);
g_pd3dDevice->IASetInputLayout(nullptr);
g_pd3dDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);
tech->GetPassByIndex(index)->Apply(0);
g_pd3dDevice->Draw(4, 0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pixel shader doesn't return the `float4` you expect. It returns in this case a `float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)`. Why? Because of the **comma operator**. The left side of the expression is ignored, and `1.0f` is implicitly converted in to a `float4`. You want to call the contructor of `float4`, like so `float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if should keep or delete my question, the mistake is the return statement:

```
return (1.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.0f);
```

should be

```
return float4(1.00f, 0.00f, 0.00f, 1.0f);
```